# Deformation of Complex Spaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, deformation-theory

I am trying to learn about deformations of complex spaces from the paper of Palamodov. I am particularly interested in the relative tangent cohomology.

Is there any other modern reference to this subject or just any reference.

Also in this paper what is an analytic $\mathbb{C}$ algebra?

Comment: It depends on your background and what exactly you want. There are very general references and others dealing with specific subjects. An introductory reference is "Advances in Moduli Theory" by Ueno and Shimizu. If you're ok with more general stuff there's Pridham's paper http://arxiv.org/pdf/0705.0344v6.pdf .